# Compiling ffmpeh for rtmp to MP4 support only

Tags: ffmpeg, unix, compile

Helly. Could I get advice on how I would compile for reduced size?

I only want http rtmp to MP4 file support.

My plan is to --disable-all then enable libh264.

What more do I want to include?
Libav*

Comment: Do you only need to mux existing H.264 + AAC streams into MP4, or do you need to be able to convert to H.264 + AAC and mux into MP4?

Comment: Yes i have to mux existing stream

Comment: Show an example of the typical ffmpeg command you will be using, and include the complete log from the command. Otherwise I have to guess what to enable.

Comment: Ffmpeg -i rtsp://... -c copy -an file.ts/mp4

Comment: Forgot rtsp_transport tcp